# XSLT for-each showing first row only

Tags: c#, xslt

Good Day,

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<company>
    <name>XYZ Inc.</name>
    <address1>One Abc Way</address1>
    <address2>Some avenue</address2>
    <city>Tech city</city>
    <country>Neverland</country>
    <products>
        <product id="123">Toaster</product>
        <product id="293">Oven</product>
        <product id="241">Egg Beater</product>
    </products>
</company>
```

and the following XSLT file:

```
<table>
    <xsl:for-each select="/company/products">
        <tr>
            <td>Product:</td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="product"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

but when I run the following C# code:

```
        string xmlFile = Path.Combine(xmlFolder, "Company.xml");
        string xsltFile = Path.Combine(xsltFolder, "Company.xslt");
        string htmlOutputFile = Path.Combine(templateFolder, "Company.html");

        XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(xmlFile);
        XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
        myXslTrans.Load(xsltFile);

        XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(htmlOutputFile, null);
        myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
```

but when I open up the resulting HTML document, only the first product displays.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Product:
        </td>
        <td>
            Toaster
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I've noticed if I used a "." instead of product in the

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Then I get all three values but on one line.

What am I missing?

TIA,

coson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're doing for-each on **products** (which you have only one of). You probably meant something like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

<table>
    <xsl:for-each select="/company/products/product">
        <tr>
            <td>Product:</td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>                    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```